# How to set material dialog direction rtl as default?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have language service that contains direction(ltr/rtl).

So when i open dialog, i specify the direction like this:

```
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SomeComponent,
      { direction: this.i18nService.dir}
    );
```

Is there a way to set the direction for all dialogs according to the service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set globals when you include providers

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}}
  ]
})
```

but I don't think you can change it globally after that.

Anyway you can always wrap the call with your own service like this:

```
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { I18nService } from './path/to/i18nService.service.ts';

@Injectable()
export class MyDialogService {
    constructor(private i18nService: I18nService, private dialog: MatDialog ) { }

    open(component: Component, config = {}): MatDialogRef {
        return this.dialog.open(component, Object.assign(config, { direction: this.i18nService.dir }));
    }
}
```

Comment: `open<T, D = any, R = any>(
        componentOrTemplateRef: ComponentType<T> | TemplateRef<T>,
        config?: MatDialogConfig<D>,
    ): MatDialogRef<T, R> {
        return this.dialog.open(componentOrTemplateRef, Object.assign(config, { direction: this.i18nService.dir }));
    }`